# How to Avoid SQL Server hangs due to uncommited transaction caused by poor SW design

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, transactions

**The problem:** a .NET application trying to save many records to SQL Server. BeginTrans was used, and right before commit a warning messages shows to end user to confirm to proceed to save data or not. The user simply left the computer and go away!!!

Now all other users are unable to access the locked records. Sometimes almost the entire system is affected. Almost all transaction are updating the same records; the confirmation message must be shown after data gets updated, and before commit so if user can rollback. What could be the best solution?

If no solution is found, the last thing i might do is to rollback, show the confirmation message, if user accepts then i will again save the data without any confirmation message (which i don't thing the right way)

My question is: What best i can do? any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like a WinForms app? It also sounds like you want to confirm the intent of user's action.  Are you in a position to only start the transaction once they confirm they intend to save the data?

Ideally, you should

1. Prompt the user via [OK | Cancel]
2. Perform the database transaction
3. If the result of the transaction is deadlock (or any other failure), inform the user the save operation failed

In other words, the update of records should be a synchronous call.

EDIT: after understanding the specifics as mentioned in the comment below, I would recommend some form of server side task queue that all these requests would need to flow through. Your client would submit a request to the server, and the server application would then become the software responsible for updating records in the database.  The clients would make their requests to this application and would be processed in the order they were received. I don't have much experience with inventory tracking software, but understand it's need to be absolutely correct.  So this is just a rough idea, I'm sure someone with more experience in inventory tracking will have a better pattern.  The proposed pattern creates a large bottleneck on the server that is responsible for updating the records.  For example, this pattern would be terrible for someone like Amazon.

Comment: Thanks, and yes ur right, its winform app, but unfortunately i must update first then i can display confirmation to user to proceed or not. the app is an Inventory Management, after i save a cash bill i need to check if an item ending balance goes negative, in some cases the user will accept and proceed, they just need a confirmation whether to proceed or not. so i can't know the SKU remaining stock in hand in advance because other users will entering cash bills too.

Comment: It sounds like you need some type of server side task queue that is shared across all running instances of your application. Will edit answer